# Css Viewing Background image through a small content

Tags: css

I have been searching all day for a tutorial on how can i have a background image that can be viewed through content that is seating on top of the page. For example if you scroll down this site

http://newsmartwave.net/magento/legenda/index.php/?___store=english3

you will see an image appears in the centre of the page and if you move further down the image disappears, it is like the image is in the background and the page is on top of it. Could someone please direct me to a tutorial that shows how can i achieve this technique? Thank you very much in advance for your support.

This site is another example

http://newsmartwave.net/magento/legenda/index.php/?___store=english7

look down at the company achievement section and see the background image that is behind it.

Comment: its parallax effect search for plugins

Comment: Thanks to both of you, if i could i would have ticked yes for both of you, however since i am only able to click on one i chose to click on the first one to direct me. again thank you both for the quick and excellent support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy to do with `background-attachment:` in css:

```
#seethrough{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    background:url(http://lorempizza.com/600/300/);
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="seethrough"></div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/hxjnzxtu/1/)
If you want-to darken it, like they do in your example, just place a div inside with a somewhat translucent background:

```
#cover{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="seethrough">
        <div id="cover">

        </div>
    </div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/hxjnzxtu/2/)
The background also has a little parallax scrolling effect.
You can find a great amount of tutorials if you  [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=parralex+scrolling+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) .
Or a pretty good one is [here](https://ihatetomatoes.net/simple-parallax-scrolling-tutorial/)
Anyway, Here is my version:
**JQuery:**

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        s = $(document).scrollTop();
        $("#seethrough").css("background-position","0px -" +  (s/2)  + "px");
    })

})
```

Same HTML and CSS, SO much more awesome!

## [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/hxjnzxtu/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for whats called parallax scrolling.

where you manipulate the background position of the background image according to the top of the using using js.

You can find many tutorials regarding this.

I picked this awesome trick myself [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-simple-parallax-scrolling-technique--net-27641).

Answer (score 1):

I have made myself a similar effect on some of my webs and I use different aproach (and more old browsers compatible). Quite simple also if well done:

the html:

```
<div class="image">
</div>
<div class="web-content1">
    first content
</div>
<div class="web-content2">
    second content
</div>
<div class="hole">
    hole
</div>
<div class="web-content3">
    third content
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.image {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-100;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url(http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs71/i/2010/135/4/0/Background_11_by_ELENADUDINA.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;
}
.web-content1, .web-content2, .web-content3, .hole {
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
.web-content1 {background-color:red;}
.web-content2 {background-color:green;}
.web-content3 {background-color:blue;}
```

here you have an example (scroll down):  http://jsfiddle.net/9rdto1hk/1/

In the web I am working at the moment you can see it used twice. first at main slider on top and second at the foot of the web: www.zimasolutions.com